# How to test on device with WorkManager's `setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)`

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm trying to setup androidx `WorkManager` to do some job once a day.

I'm setting my job like this

```
val request = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(Worker::class.java, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .setConstraints(
                Constraints.Builder()
                        .setRequiresCharging(true)
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED)
                        .setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)
                        .build()
        )
        .build()

workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
        "my-job-name",
        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
        request
)
```

And my `Worker` class has some logging.

I'm trying to verify that this is working. The problem is I can't see any of my logging in logcat. However it works fine when I remove `setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)` constraint. Can anyone point out how can I put my phone in the state which works with `setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)`?

I tried

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
```

But this isn't working. Also I tried turning off screen and forwarding clocks to next day and so on. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

If it's testing that were talking about, the best option is to use WorkManager's `WorkManagerTestInitHelper` and its capability to drive directly the [`testDriver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/testing/TestDriver.html).

```
// Create request
val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
val testDriver = WorkManagerTestInitHelper.getTestDriver()

testDriver.setAllConstraintsMet(request.id)
```

You can find more information in the [testing documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/testing#simulation)